# Why am i getting these encode string rather then GPS coordinates in arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVCM9.png)

I am using this repository.

Comment: You should add more details

Answer (score 0):

No code?  No repository link?  Try the diagnostic program in my library [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS).